# How to fix Integer.intValue() for RTL languages in Android

Tags: java, android

In my application I write some codes and this codes I used string.
I want use UTF-8 languages (Farsi), But after run application show me error and force close application.
But when use English language not show me any error and run successfully!!

**My codes :**

```
this.q.put("dry land swim", Integer.valueOf(R.array.dry_land_swim));

            TypedArray obtainTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(((Integer) this.q.get(stringArray[i])).intValue());
            int length = obtainTypedArray.length();
            int[] iArr2 = new int[length];
            WorkoutData workoutData = new WorkoutData();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length; i2++) {
                iArr2[i2] = obtainTypedArray.getResourceId(i2, -1);
            }
            workoutData.setExcName(stringArray[i]);
            Log.e("ShowError", "" + (this.r.get(stringArray[i])).intValue());
            workoutData.setExcDescResId(((Integer) this.r.get(stringArray[i])).intValue());
```

**When change this line text (from En to Fa) :**

```
this.q.put("تست", Integer.valueOf(R.array.dry_land_swim));
```

**Show me error for this lines** :

```
TypedArray obtainTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(((Integer) this.q.get(stringArray[i])).intValue());
workoutData.setExcDescResId(((Integer) this.r.get(stringArray[i])).intValue());
```

Error message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.crazytrends.healthmanager.WalkandStep.receivers.HardwareStepCountReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.crazytrends.healthmanager/.WalkandStep.services.HardwareStepCounterService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{528e8bd u0a841 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:301)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.crazytrends.healthmanager/.WalkandStep.services.HardwareStepCounterService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{528e8bd u0a841 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1795)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1740)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:738)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:738)
        at com.crazytrends.healthmanager.WalkandStep.receivers.HardwareStepCountReceiver.onReceive(HardwareStepCountReceiver.java:22)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4443)
```

How can I Fix it?

Comment: did you register your intent listener to your manifest to be able to listen and call your reciever?

Comment: `Not allowed to start service Intent`